# local PHP file doesn't open in browser

Tags: php, xampp, local

I just installed XAMPP on my Windows 7 PC, and wanted to test it with a local PHP file. Double-clicking the file opens a new tab in my browser (Firefox 16.0.1) but the file doesn't open. Instead the tab's label flashes between "connecting" and "new tab" about once per second, and I have a hard time closing the tab again.

I stopped Apache and even ended XAMPP, but no joy. Even reducing the file to the bare minimum doesn't help:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>php test</title>
</head>
<body>
    Lorem Ipsum...
</body>
</html>
```

Firefox does open the file if I rename it to a `.htm` file.

Any ideas what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Is the file inside the `RootDirectory` you've specified for Apache?

Comment: is the file in xamp\htdocs folder??

Comment: Apparently your php parser isnt working properly. I would try an xampp forum for this

Comment: Even locally you have to use the http: protocol specifier to look the result of a file interpreted by php and sent by apache to your browser. With the file: protocol specifier, you see the only source...

Comment: @david - Yep (in a subfolder, actually)

Comment: @Havelock - I can't seem to find `RootDirectory` in any of the config files. Can you tell me where I should add it?

Comment: @stevenvh that's the path david strachan mentioned.

Comment: @downvoter - I don't mind a downvote, at least not if the downvoter isn't too cowardly to explain his downvote.

Answer (score 2):

You cant load the file in browser by doubleclicking in the explorer window, you load it through http protocol:

```
http://localhost:8080/folder/file.php
```

Where 
- 8080 should be your XAMPP port if not 80
- folder is the subfolder to htdocs if any
- file.php is your script

Answer (score 2):

You can't just "open" (per double click, as you described) a `.php` file in your browser. At the very least, because the browser can't interpret PHP.
You need to send a proper (HTTP) request to the server, which will then pass the PHP code to the interpreter, get the results of it and forward it to the browser - in an (for the browser) understandable (e.g. HTML) form over a proper (HTTP) response.

To be able to initially play around with PHP, create an `index` file (php or html) on which just set links to your `.php`files, so you can see them in your browser.

**Add**
Just saw your comment, then you should be able to see the file in your browser, going to `http://localhost/your-subfolder/file.php`.

The difference: now you're requesting the file through it's URL (`http://some.domain/some-file.php`) as it usually happens for websites. What you tried first was to open it through it's location on the file system (when you see `file:///path/to/some-file.php` in the address bar of your browser).

Comment: OK, fixed, thanks. Seems I expected too much from the collaboration between XAMPP server and Firefox. Is there a way to pass to `localhost` automagically when I try to open a local PHP file? (Maybe expecting to much again?)

Comment: You always need to call it "through" the server (apache) from the browser, and *not* from the file system. You could have more than one `localhost`, that is `VirtualHost`s, i.e. `http://mysite1.dev`, `http://mysite2.dev`, `http://myothersite.localhost`, etc. Not sure how to make it exactly in XAMPP but Apache2 (which is run by XAMPP) supports it 100%. Just check the docs for XAMPP how to set up `VirtualHost`s.

Answer (score 0):

i spent hours trying to fix this just to realize that the folder hadn't been given permissions...if you're using Linux make sure have.